# Remove Windows 10 quick monitor shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-10

No idea how it's called, but I get this, when I move stuff around my desktop:

[image]

It kinda lets you quickly put items on different monitors (those are 3), but its super annoying.

Anyone knows what it is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is not a native function of Windows 10. You have a program installed (probably came with your computer) that does this. These programs usually are called grid, gridmove, etc. You may have an icon in your system tray too that you can close. Once you found it, simply uninstall it to stop it from returning.

Comment: @LPChip I don't have any one those installed :/

Comment: It is possible this feature comes with your graphicscard drivers too.

Comment: Still didn't find anything. I added list of active programs, maybe that helps :/

Comment: Try to use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see what program logs in process monitor when you move something in desktop.

Comment: Thank you @Biswa, your idea helped me. Please add it as answer and I can close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following [@Biswa](https://superuser.com/users/726810/biswa) suggestion, I moved some stuff around and checked the process log (what action is beeing called) and found out that It was MSI True Color settings:

[image]

Comment: Add more details like what you see  in process explorer, details of that process, what filters you've applied, some small screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Check if turning off these setting s under Make the mouse easier to use can work for you:

Turn off all Easy use of mouse features:

[image]

Comment: No, those are not related to the issue

Answer (score 0):

That overlay looks a bit like the one from the Dell PremierColor Display Splitter application. I think you can turn it of in the advanced settings under "Display Splitter" here: [image: Dell PremierColor Display Splitter]